# How to find an index position of first occurrence of forward slash in URL?

Tags: java, substring

How to find an index position of first occurrence of `/` forward slash from this string?

```
String str = "http://somewhere.com/abc";
```

I've tried with `str.substring(str.indexOf('/'))` but it returns `//somewhere.com/abc`. What I want is extracting `/abc` only.

Comment: Well, you want the index of the **last** slash, not the first. The first slash is the slash coming right after `http:`. The javadoc is your friend.

Comment: If any number of slashes can occur e.g. `http://somewhere.com/abc/xyz/def` and protocol is fixed then you can use a variant of `indexOf` as `str.indexOf('/', str.indexOf('://') + 3)` (Start looking for '/' from index 7)

Comment: Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Or just do this. str.substring(str.IndexOf(".com/")+4)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I DO:  String str = "http://somewhere.com/abc"; String [] arr= str.split("/"); String string = arr[arr.length-1];